# How do I shrink an array and relocating data from another array?

Tags: java

Assuming my method would fail if this list is less than 1 in size and the last element is `null`?

I am suppose to use the following type of method.

```
private boolean decreaseArray() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Arrays cannot be decreased once they're declared, use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: The summary of this question makes sense, but the entire body confuses me...

Answer (score 0):

Since this sounds like homework, I'm just going to give you a few guidelines to the solution according to my interpretation to your question.

If you have a sparsely populated array of length n and size m (m < n), and you want to "free up" some memory, what you could do is create a new array of length m and simply move the elements to that array and let GC take care of everything else accordingly.

However, using List interface is preferred, and if you need array-backed implementation, ArrayList.

Note that ArrayList can indeed reserve more memory than the exaxt number of elements it contains, but if you wish, you can subclass List interface and provide your own implementation of your own ArrayList that grows by one as the insert is happening, or shrinks by one in case of removal. However, that implementation would be really bad because you would have to copy entire list before and after any editing operation, which would put a simple add and remove methods at O(n) time complexity, which is bad.

Another alternative is using linkef lists, bur they inherently come with extra space overhead due to using non-primitive structures which contain actual elements as well as references to adjacent nodes.

Comment: thanks, the first method is what i am looking for. List interface.

private boolean decreaseArray() {
if (creatureList[creatureList.length - 1] == null) {
   
     
 System.out.println("Last index of array is null");
   
     
 Creature[] newlist = new Creature[creatureList.length - 1];
     
      
 for (int i = 0; i < creatureList.length; i++){
         newlist[i] = creatureList[i];
 }
 creatureList = newlist;
     
 return true;
 }
else;
   
 return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but it kind of sounds like you're describing [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) or [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {

    static <A> A[] decreaseArray(A[] as) {
        return Arrays.copyOf(as, as.length - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(
            decreaseArray(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"})));
        // [a, b]

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(
            decreaseArray(new String[] {})));
        // java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i wish i can do that. but im really limited to that method, i cannot call my own method.